# Child which is flex container not respecting container height on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I have a flex container (`.child2`) which is a child of a fixed-height container (`.container`). Though it's `flex-direction` is `column`, `flex-wrap` is `wrap` and it's children should and could create a second column to fit inside the container, they don't and overflow the container on Firefox. They do respect container's height on Chrome.

How could I force Firefox to behave as Chrome does without declaring flex container's height?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <ul class="child2">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 350px;
}

.child1 {
  height: 28px;
}

.child2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

ul > li {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evoLbb

Comment: Add `min-height: 0` to `.child2`.